# Sending a parameter to Telnet using TCL

Tags: tcl, telnet

I am trying to create a script using TCL to configure a router via telnet. 
but I am not able to pass a Parameter to telent . 
What I need the command to look like is : "Bandwidth 10 10"
a = 10 . 
when sending

Bandwidth 10 10 - all is working 
but when sending Bandwidth $a $a - says invalid command.

what I tried is :

'Bandwidth $a $a' - in this case I do see 10 10 , but it doesn't recognize bandwidth as a command.

other cases like : 
{Bandwidth '$a $a') || {Bandwidth '$a' '$a'} || {Bandwidth $a $a} || {Bandwidth [ expr ($a) expr ($a)]  doesnt work for me.

this is the code :

```
activate_commands_via_telnet $RouterWanIP [list {bandwidth '$a $a'} {exit}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try doing this?

```
activate_commands_via_telnet $RouterWanIP [list "bandwidth $a $a" {exit}]
```

The double quotes allow Tcl to substitute the value of the `a` variable inside there.